# What is the best approach when training and HDR model with LDR data?

Tags: computer-vision, machine-learning, preprocessing

I am working on this project ["EMLight"](https://github.com/fnzhan/EMLight).

- Data: HDR Panoramic Photos
- y: Illumination Map of the Panorama
- X: HDR Croppings from the Panorama

I want to make this project work with LDR photos, and a question arose:

**Should I train with LDR representations from the HDR crops, *OR* train with the HDR crops to infer with HDR representations of LDR images?**

My instincts tell me to train with LDR representations, choosing to extract the informations from the richer data rather than "interpolating" the LDR data.

As I do more research, it feels like a more complicated problem and wanted to see if there are people with experience on working with HDR/LDR data.

Thanks.